# Find and replace inside one csv column with powershell

Tags: powershell, search, csv, replace, find

I have a large CSV file that looks like this named student.export.text

Student Number,Last Name,Middle Name,First Name,Schoolid,Grade Level,Dob

I'm trying to build an automated task that will run nightly so that another piece of software can understand the CSV correctly.

Here is my code, but I'm missing something that is causing an error.  I am new to Powershell and I am hoping for some advice.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
$Replacements = @{
  "5" = "AE";
  "7" = "ER";
  "10" = "FM";
  "12" = "HC";
  "14" = "JH";
  "18" = "LE";

    #...]
}


Import-Csv .\student.export.text | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Schoolid = $Replacements[$_.Schoolid]
    $_
} | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation .\new.csv
```

Comment: This can absolutely be done with Powershell. In fact there's probably a half dozen different ways to do it.  What have you tried?

Comment: To be honest with you I've not managed to do anything correctly except open the original export and change the header row so the software can understand it for the input.  I am completely new to powershell and don't know where to start.  Can you help?

Comment: You can try starting here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee221100.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach that can work.

```
# declare hash table with School ID to School Name mapping
$schoolIdsToNames = @{
  "3" = "SchoolA";
  "4" = "SchoolB"
}

# import the CSV file
$csv = Import-Csv "C:\input.csv";

# for each row, replace the School ID field with the School Name
foreach($row in $csv) 
{
    $row.Schoolid = $schoolIdsToNames[$row.Schoolid];
}

# export the modified CSV
$csv | Export-Csv  "C:\replaced.csv" -NoTypeInformation;
```

In the first step, we set up a PowerShell hashtable (a sort of key-value pair list), then import the CSV file using `Import-Csv` and store it in the `$csv` variable. This cmdlet will create an object from every row of the CSV that we can manipulate easily. For each row, we simply replace the `Schoolid` field with the value assigned to the ID key in the `$schoolIdsToNames` hashtable. Finally, we export the CSV to another file.

Another, more PowerShell-ly approach would be something like this:

```
Import-Csv "C:\test\school.csv" | Select-Object *, @{ Name = "SchoolName"; Expression = { $schoolIdsToNames[$_.Schoolid] } } | Export-Csv "C:\test\replaced2.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

This one-liner imports the CSV and sends it down the pipeline. For each row, we select all properties of the row using `Select-Object` and add a new property called `SchoolName`, setting its value using the same hash table-based technique as above. Finally, we export the object list to CSV.

Comment: I keep getting this error from running your code.   Index operation failed; the array index evaluated to null.
At line:30 char:5
+     $row.Schoolid = $schoolIdsToNames[$row.Schoolid];
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArrayIndex

Comment: I got it working!  I had a problem inside the import file.  THANK YOU!